# Identity Usermanager DeleteAsync DbUpdateConcurrencyException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

I am trying to delete a user via the aspnetcore.identity UserManager behind a webapi.

```
    [HttpPost("Delete", Name = "DeleteRoute")]
    [Authorize(Roles = "SuperUser")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteAsync([FromBody] User user)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Deleting user: " + user.Id);
        try {
            await _userManager.DeleteAsync(user);
            return Ok();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return BadRequest(e.Message);
        }

    }
```

This throws a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`

```
   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ThrowAggregateUpdateConcurrencyException(Int32 commandIndex, Int32 expectedRowsAffected, Int32 rowsAffected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeResultSetWithoutPropagationAsync(Int32 commandIndex, RelationalDataReader reader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeAsync(RelationalDataReader reader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(DbContext _, ValueTuple`2 parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IReadOnlyList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ThrowAggregateUpdateConcurrencyException(Int32 commandIndex, Int32 expectedRowsAffected, Int32 rowsAffected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeResultSetWithoutPropagationAsync(Int32 commandIndex, RelationalDataReader reader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeAsync(RelationalDataReader reader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(DbContext _, ValueTuple`2 parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IReadOnlyList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Im aware that this exception is usually indicating race conditions, but I dont get why that happens.

Am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT**

The user object i post looks something like this:

```
"User": {
 "Email": "",
 "FirstName": "",
 "LastName": "",
 "Gender": "",
 "Affiliation": {
     "isStudent": true,
     "isEmployee": false
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: A concurrency violation occurs when an unexpected number of rows are affected during save. This is usually because the **data in the database has been modified since it was loaded into memory**. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbupdateconcurrencyexception)

In your case, the User object that is received by the controller may not have the same values in the database.  As suggested by @KirkLarkin, you can get the User Object using User ID and then call the delete method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Entity Framework Core uses [Optimistic Concurrency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/optimistic-concurrency):

> In an optimistic concurrency model, a violation is considered to have occurred if, after a user receives a value from the database, another user modifies the value before the first user has attempted to modify it.

Contrast this with Pessimistic Concurrency:

> ...in a pessimistic concurrency model, a user who updates a row establishes a lock. Until the user has finished the update and released the lock, no one else can change that row.

In order to achieve Optimistic Concurrency, the `IdentityUser` class contains a [`ConcurrencyStamp`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/3.0/src/Identity/Extensions.Stores/src/IdentityUser.cs#L106) property (and corresponding column in the database), which is a string-representation of a GUID:

```
public virtual string ConcurrencyStamp { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

Every time a user is saved to the database, the `ConcurrencyStamp` gets set to a new GUID.

Taking the example of deleting a user, a simplified version of the `DELETE` SQL statement sent to the server might look something like the following:

```sql
DELETE FROM dbo.AspNetUsers
WHERE Id = '<USER_ID>' AND ConcurrencyStamp = '<CONCURRENCY_STAMP>'
```

The error message you receive occurs when the `CONCURRENCY_STAMP` value in the SQL statement above does not match the value stored in the database for the given user. This ensures that if you retrieve a user from the database (which contains a specific `ConcurrencyStamp`), you can only save changes to the database if no other changes have been made elsewhere (as you're providing the same `ConcurrencyStamp` value that existed in the database).

As you can see from the `ConcurrencyStamp` definition above, the property defaults to a new `GUID` - every time an `IdentityUser` (or subclass) is created, it gets a new `ConcurrencyStamp` value. In your example, with the `User` that is passed in to your `DeleteAsync` action, ASP.NET Core Model-Binding first creates a new instance of `User` and then sets the properties that exist in the JSON payload. As there is no `ConcurrencyStamp` value in the payload, `User` will end up with a *new* `ConcurrencyStamp` value that will not match that in the database.

To avoid this problem, you *could* add the `ConcurrencyStamp` value into your payload sent from the client. However, I wouldn't recommend this. The simplest and safest approach to resolving this issue would be to send the `Id` of the `User` as the payload, retrieve the `User` itself using `_userManager.FindByIdAsync` and then using *that* instance to perform the delete. Here's an example:

```
[HttpPost("Delete/{id}", Name = "DeleteRoute")]
[Authorize(Roles = "SuperUser")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteAsync(string id)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Deleting user: " + id);
    try {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);

        if(user == null)
            // ... 

        await _userManager.DeleteAsync(user);
        return Ok();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return BadRequest(e.Message);
    }
}
```